# html tags restriction

Tags: javascript, html, regex, entities

`<h1>test</h1>` works perfect, but when I try `< h1>test< /h1>` it doesn't work, I cannot have a character placed right next to the less than `<` symbol, is there anyway to execute the html code with just a space next to the less than symbol?

Example: `< script>`, `< h1>`, `< b>`, `< p>`? I really need to be able to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to allow incorrect html tags to work?

Comment: i'm trying to see if i can upload html code in a message on my platform, i managed to block symbols next to `<`

Comment: @AlexXwalewx use markdown, if you want html support. Don't roll your own validation to check if there's html or not. What if I want to write a cute little `<3`?

Comment: Do not, dot not, dot not (stressed enough?) parse HTML with regex. HTML is a "context free grammar" and regex parses "regular" type grammars. There are instances where it will fail. Take the other advice already given and just don't do this in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 5):

What you've describing is just not how HTML works. From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags):

> **12.1.2.1 Start tags**
>
> **Start tags** must have the following format:
>
> 1. The first character of a start tag must be a U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN character (`<`).
> 2. The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.
> 3. ...

Tag names cannot contain spaces, so you can't have a space after the `<` and have it be a start tag. (Instead, it's just the character `<`.)

Comment: `< ...` wouldn't be just considered to be text?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Yes, that's what the answer says. (I briefly said it was invalid, but fixed it -- hit refresh, maybe you're seeing an old copy?)

Comment: Nope, I said it before you edited. But anyways, it's fixed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Not *quite*, but in any case, it's correct now. :-)

Comment: so there's no way to place a space before `<`?

Comment: @AlexXwalewx No, it is not possible since it violates the requirements for a start tag.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck - **Before** is fine; it'll be a space in the document. You can't have a space **after** `<` and still have it be a start tag.

Comment: @AdamChubbuck - Sorry, got my @ notification wrong. :-) That was meant for Alex.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No problem! =)